# Automatic updates of timeline activity dates

Tags: civicase

I am finding that timelines in civicase assign dates for activities based on when the case is opened, which means timeline dates are rarely accurate to when they should occur.

Let's assume that "Open Case" is the first activity, "Course Start Date" is the next one, and all later activities are offset from "Course Start Date". Is there a way for the dates associated with all later activities to be adjusted when "Course Start Date" is modified after opening the new case?

Answer (score 3):

The default timeline that is specified in the Case Types configuration allows you to specify the reference activity (i.e. which activity should provide the reference point for any time offset) and the amount of the offset (i.e. how many days before/after) for any given activity that is going to be in the default timeline. So, in your example, you want 'Course Start Date' to be the reference for all subsequent activities.

Having said that, when you create the case, I think that all the offset calculations are done at that point in time, so even if you then subsequently set a date for the 'Course Start Date' activity, I don't think subsequent activity dates will automagically adjust as we might like them to.

Answer (score 2):

Define a secondary timeline called e.g. post-course, which has your post-course tasks. Then when you know the course date, add that timeline using Add Timeline on the manage case screen.

You may also want to consider sequences, which don't have set offsets, but get created in order when the previous task completes, although it may not quite be what you're looking for.
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/case-management/set-up/

Answer (score 0):

*when you create the case, I think that all the offset calculations are done at that point in time, so even if you then subsequently set a date for the 'Course Start Date' activity, I don't think subsequent activity dates will automagically adjust as we might like them to.*

Has this been fixed yet in CiviCase? This is a huge problem for my set-up, and I was looking for an answer and am very disappointed this is the reality. If there is an update on how to make this happen, TIA!